# Why there are orders of magnitude in the evaluation of torch.sin() and numpy.sin() at integer multiples of Pi?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, precision, tensor

Why are trigonometric functions of Pytorch and Numpy when evaluated at integer multiples of Pi result in such huge discrepancy in the orders of magnitude?

```
>>> torch.sin(torch.ones(1)*2*np.pi)
tensor([1.7485e-07])
>>> np.sin(np.ones(1)*2*np.pi)
array([-2.4492936e-16])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Torch defaults to 32-bit floats, while NumPy defaults to 64-bit. The rounding error you're getting in Torch is around the expected scale for 32-bit floats. Specify a different dtype if you want a different dtype.

Comment: Thanks, but why would the default dtype precision be different for these two packages? is that because precision matters less for the applications that concerns torch (deep learning) ?

Comment: @mimain Pretty much. Also, since pytorch is designed for GPU acceleration, using FP64 doubles the amount of gpu memory needed to store model parameters and gradients. Furthermore, consumer GPUs don't usually have very good FP64 performance (latency wise) and can be as much as 20 or 30 times slower than FP32.

Comment: Thanks @jodag that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on the answer you got, but using plain Python:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sin(2 * math.pi)
-2.4492935982947064e-16
```

Python uses 64-bit floats, and that's a close match to the `numpy` result.

IEEE-754 64-bit floats have 53 bits of precision, but 32-bit floats only 24. So let's round the input back to 24 significant bits and see what happens:

```
>>> x = 2 * math.pi
>>> m, e = math.frexp(x)
>>> m *= 2**24
>>> m = round(m)
>>> y = math.ldexp(m, e - 24)
>>> math.sin(y)
1.7484556000744883e-07
```

And that's a close match to the `torch` result.